# In Windows 10, what is Out Of Box Experience (OOBE)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

There are 3 updates for Windows 10 as of 28 August 2015.

[OOBE Update for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081449)

[Cumulative Update for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081448)

[Compatibility Update for Upgrading to Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081452)

Out of these 3, I only got the OOBE and Compatibility Update for my System of which I understand that the Compatibility Update is possibly fixing issues with updating to Windows 10 but what I don't get is the Out Of Box Experience. What does this update do exactly? Does it improve existing Windows 10 features or is it adding new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is OOBEE?**
*Out-of-box experience (OOBE pronounced oo-bee) is the experience a consumer (or user) has when preparing to first use a new product. In relation to computing, this includes the setup process of installing and/or performing initial configuration of a piece of hardware or software on a computer. This generally follows the point-of-sale experience or the interaction experience of an expert user. (source Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-box_experience)*

Basically - all it is, is the 'script' that runs and configures everything when you first turn on a fresh install of windows 10.

Those updates you've listed, effectively just add more config steps to those initial scripts that are run.

**To summarise** - if you're running windows 10 now, and are happy. Don't worry about them!

Comment: So adding new script's to the star-up won't it delay the already slow response,and why now these updates i.e already I have migrated and there won't be any new fresh install or a fresh start-up

Comment: It's not adding it to general startup - it only adds them to the first ever startup.

It's in case you ever SYSPREP - but that's a different story. If you're happy now, ignore it. All the new updates you've stated do is replace specific windows updates etc. Something which will be done automatically anyway. It's just a way of streamlining from Microsoft I imagine

Comment: You would only experience OOBE if you reset the computer, it is the sequence of questions that you get when you first open up the computer (username, password, license key, accept the license agreement, etc.) Organizations also experience the OOBE if the prepare a copy of Windows from one computer (an image) for deployment to lots of other computers (so they can all be set up with the same software, configuration, etc.)